# Haskell $ operator in practical use

Tags: haskell, operators, operator-precedence

I am trying to get my head around in Haskell expressions using `$` operator. Specifically on how to write this in Haskell using `$` operator or another if required:

```
add 1 (add (subtract 2 4) (subtract 8 16))
```

I managed to remove two paren groups as in:

```
add 1 $ add (subtract 2 4) $ subtract 8 16
```

But still need to remove the last pair.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are `add` and `subtract`? How are they defined?

Comment: Not sure that matters, but for this case `add = (+)` and `subtract = flip (-)`.

Comment: Note that `$` and `.` are not necessarily meant to remove parentheses in all cases. The most important use is to make a *chain* of applications `f1 (f2 (f3 (f4 x)))` more readable by transforming it into a form of "pipe" `f1 $ f2 $ f3 $ f4 $ x` or `(f1 . f2 . f3 . f4) x`. This doesn't work with functions that take more than one argument.

Comment: well that's clear, thanks. I want to make sure this is not possible or how if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can try infix form

```
add 1 $ subtract 2 4 `add` subtract 8 16
```

**EDIT**

There is other way.

Lets define:

```
newtype W a = W { w :: a } 

pure' = W

(.$.) :: W (a -> b) -> a -> W b
(.$.) (W a) b = W $ a b
```

and operation to use for example

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus = (+)
```

Then we can do next

```
foo :: Int
foo = w $ pure' plus .$. plus 1 2  .$.  2
```

It is basically applicative functor (you can google it for examples) just with different names.

You prefix your operation with `w $ pure'` and separate arguments with `.$.`.

Comment: The reason of using `add` and `subtract` is to make it work with prefix. Eventually, I am not trying to solve anything, just trying to figure out ways to use `$` oparetor.

Comment: You can use prefix `+` for example `(+) 1 2`.

Comment: yes, I know but still it won't work with the expression in the question.

Comment: Yes. There is no way it will work without parenthesis.

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to apply your `pure'`/`(.$.)` pair to the original problem?

Comment: @chepner you can write that expression without parentheses `add 1 $ w $ pure' add .$. subtract 2 4 .$. subtract 8 16`